# How to dynamically wait until external SOAP Web Service Return a response

Tags: apex, callout, webservices, soap

I've built an external SOAP Web Service that takes several minutes to complete, I need to do some logic depending on the Service Response.

Should I set a large timeOut value?
Is there a way to use While clause to evaluate the Service response?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One what to do this is with continuations. It's a callback mechanism that is built into Visualforce. See [Make Long-Running Callouts from a Visualforce Page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_continuation_overview.htm).

[image]

You can also use them from Lightning - [Invoking Apex Continuations from Lightning Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2017/09/invoking-apex-continuations-lightning-components.html). Or a more official version from Summer '19 - [Make Long-Running Callouts with Continuations](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_lc_continuations.htm).